# Cost function reduction using coordinate descent using scipy optimize

Tags: python, scipy

I have a cost function dependent on three variables.
Hence, trying to use cyclic coordinate descent.

I cannot see any mention of coordinate descent in scipy.optimize
Since, i am new to Python, i am unable to understand whether i need to write everything from scratch or if i could use any of the scipy.optimize methods.

Any hint or ideas are welcome.

Further information: I am trying to implement this paper's proposed method "User Profiling in Ego Network: An Attribute and Relationship Type Co-profiling Approach".
Using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paper you refer to apparently requires optimization of a problem with some variables *discrete*. You are probably not really looking for coordinate descent, but mixed integer programming/continuous optimization solver.

scipy.optimize does not have integer programming solvers, but you may have some luck with those listed in http://scipy.org/topical-software.html#optimization

Alternatively, if the problem is not too difficult, solutions may be found with scipy.optimize derivative free solvers (simplex and powell) by just coercing continuous variables to discrete ones.

Comment: Will try Powell and simplex. Thanks.